# The best way to get counts of occurrences

Tags: sql, count

I have the following data structure :

```
FIRSTNAME    AGE    NICKNAME
Jack         28     Benny
Robert       30     Benny
Pascal       20     Benny
Charles      19     Lence
Anthony      20     Lence
```

The first column is unique.
The idea is that I have to count how many times the "nickname" is used and I want to output it so that I can I have the following result :

```
Benny    3
Lence    2
```

What is the best performant way to do so knowing that I have millions of lines?

Comment: Should Benny have a count of 3 instead of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT NICKNAME,COUNT(NICKNAME)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY NICKNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT NICKNAME, SUM(1) FROM table GROUP BY NICKNAME

Answer (score 0):

agregate count group by firstname, there's no other solution.

by the way, the benny nickname only appears 3 times, not 4.